# orthogonally intersecting families

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Take two families of circles
$$
(x-c_1)^2+y^2=c_1^2\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad x^2+(y-c_2)^2=c_2^2\;,
$$
where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are positive constants. Use the gradient to show that these two families intersect orthogonally.

Attempt: Let $f(x,y)=(x-c_1)^2+y^2-c_1^2$ and $g(x,y)=x^2+(y-c_2)^2-c_2^2$. Then
$\nabla f (x,y)=(2(x-c_1),2y)$ and $\nabla g(x,y)=(2x,2(y-c_2))$. However, I'm not sure how one could go about establishing that
$$
\nabla f(x,y)\cdot\nabla g(x,y) = 0.
$$
I have thought about working in polar coordinates, but this has not helped either. Any ideas, please?

Comment: Hint: Note that you are trying to prove they INTERSECT orthogonally, so any property of the intersection points?

Comment: Any comments on my answer?

Comment: There are two intersecting points. One is the origin, and the other one is non-trivial. I did compute the dot product at these two points, and it is zero. So I guess that settles my problem. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

First establish some useful relations at intersection points, per @SecretMath's comment. Namely
$$
\left \{ \begin{array}{ccc}
(x-c_1)^2 + y^2 & = & c_1^2 \\
x^2 + (y-c_2)^2 & = & c_2^2
\end{array} \right . \implies \left \{ \begin{array}{ccc}
x^2 - 2c_1x + y^2 & = & 0 \\
x^2 + y^2 - 2c_2y & = & 0
\end{array} \right . \implies \left \{ \begin{array}{lcl}
c_1 x & = & c_2y = A\\
x^2 + y^2 & = & 2A
\end{array} \right .
$$
So $\nabla f \cdot \nabla g = 4x(x-c_1) + 4y(y-c_2) = 4(x^2+y^2-c_1x-c_2y) = 4(2A - A - A) = 0$